# How can I enable unauthenticated user to activate himself?

Tags: users

How can I enable unauthenticated user to activate himself? not to wait for administrator activation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided we're talking about Drupal 7:

1. Navigate to: *Administration » Configuration » People »  Account settings*.
2. Under: "Registration and cancellation. Who can register accounts?", check the radio button for "Visitors".
3. Click "Save configuration" at the bottom of the page.